# Is there any way to avoid having to write ".call" on lambdas and procs?

Tags: ruby

I often create small lambdas inside my functions to handle repeated tasks, for instance (contrived example):

```
def some_method(foo)
  match = SOME_REGEX.match foo

  has_component = lambda { |name|
    match.names.include? name and not match[name].nil?
  }

  if has_component.call("street_name")
    # ...
  end

  if has_component.call("house_number")
    # ...
  end

  if has_component.call("entrance")
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

Now I don't know about you, but I would much rather write:

```
  if has_component "street_name"
    # ...
  end

  if has_component "house_number"
    # ...
  end

  if has_component "entrance"
    # ...
  end
```

I'm not familiar with the inner workings of Ruby, but is there anything I can do with my lambda/proc to make it callable as if it was a `def`ined function?

There are multiple reasons why I don't want to define the lambda/proc on a class level as a method. Among other things, it won't have access to the scope of the caller.

Comment: From the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide): *"Prefer `proc.call()` over `proc[]` or `proc.()` for both lambdas and procs."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use subscript operator

```
if has_component['entrance']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
has_component.('entrance')
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Ruby 1.9.0, there is syntactic sugar for `call`:

```
b.call(1, 2, 3)
b.(1, 2, 3)
```

This one is the preferred way, since it works with *everything* that responds to `call`, not just `Proc`s.

Alternatively, you could just define a shorter method name:

```
class Proc
  alias_method :c, :call
end

b.c(1, 2, 3)
```

Or an even shorter method name:

```
class Proc
  alias_method :[], :call
end

c[1, 2, 3]
```

And in fact, the latter one is already defined in the Ruby core library.

It is not possible to make calling `Proc`s look like calling methods, because there is an ambiguity: does `b(1, 2, 3)` mean "call method `b` with arguments `1, 2, 3`" or does it mean "call method `b` without arguments (or dereference local variable `b`) and call the `Proc` returned by `b` with arguments `1, 2, 3`"? In ECMAScript and Python, this works because they simply don't allow calling methods without parentheses, so this ambiguity never arises.

Comment: The ambiguity would disappear if there way some way of converting the `Proc` into a method just for the current local scope. This is probably not useful enough to warrant any thought from the language's maintainers though.